# How to hide calendar under the menu bar when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<br />
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px;margin-top:30px;">
  <p><b>This example demonstrates how to hide a navbar when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
  
  
  <p>Scroll down this frame to see the effect!</p>
  <p>Scroll up to show the navbar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline:true,
    });
})
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
</script>


</body>
<!-- XDSoft DateTimePicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-DOS9W6NR+NFe1fUhEE0PGKY/fubbUCnOfTje2JMDw3Y=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha256-FEqEelWI3WouFOo2VWP/uJfs1y8KJ++FLh2Lbqc8SJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

- I am using the following calendar with Django:
  https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
- Problem is that when scrolling down the page, Month and Year calendar
  components goes over my menu-bar. There is a way to fix this ? maybe
  to override some css from the calendar or in my HTML/Javascript ?
- I reproduced my scenario within an HTML example from w3school. See code snipped.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No need to be set such a high z-index value for inline calendar since
  is not showing up over the date field like the default calendar.
- Instead of `z-index: 9999` use `z-index: 101` like the dropdowns for
  month and year uses. Solution is to override calendar's css:

  ```
   <script>
   .xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label {
       z-index: 101 !important;
   }
   </script>
  ```